# MySQL query to select a record from each group that meets a user-defined criterion

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am looking for a query that selects a record from each group that meets a user-defined criterion.  I can explain with the following illustrative table:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table
(
  id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
  categoryID INT,
  weight INT,

  PRIMARY KEY(id)  
);

INSERT INTO sample_table(categoryID, weight) VALUES(1, 3), (1, 5), (1, 2), (2, 5), (2, 3), (2, 9), (3, 5), (3, 3), (3, 3);
```

A simple `GROUP BY categoryID` query returns the first record in each group, as shown below:

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table GROUP BY categoryID;
+----+------------+--------+
| id | categoryID | weight |
+----+------------+--------+
|  1 |          1 |      3 |
|  4 |          2 |      5 |
|  7 |          3 |      5 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

To return the last record in each group we can use the approach [suggested here](https://paulund.co.uk/get-last-record-in-each-mysql-group):

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM sample_table GROUP BY categoryID);
+----+------------+--------+
| id | categoryID | weight |
+----+------------+--------+
|  3 |          1 |      2 |
|  6 |          2 |      9 |
|  9 |          3 |      3 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

**However**, what I want to do is to select the record which the highest value for the `weight` field in each group.  My output, therefore, should be:

```
+----+------------+--------+
| id | categoryID | weight |
+----+------------+--------+
|  2 |          1 |      5 |
|  6 |          2 |      9 |
|  7 |          3 |      3 |
+----+------------+--------+
```

---

Kindly suggest the `GROUP BY categoryID` query which will yield the above output.

Comment: It's nonsensical to include `*` and `GROUP BY` in the same query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "modern" way of doing this on MySQL 8+ would be to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY categoryID ORDER BY weight DESC) rn
    FROM sample_table
)

SELECT id, categoryID, weight
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

On earlier versions, you may use a join approach:

```sql
SELECT t1.id, t1.categoryID, t1.weight
FROM sample_table t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT categoryID, MAX(weight) AS max_weight
    FROM sample_table
    GROUP BY categoryID
) t2
    ON t2.categoryID = t1.categoryID AND
       t2.max_weight = t1.weight;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for:

```
SELECT id, categoryID, weight
FROM sample_table ret
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT *
  FROM sample_table witness
  WHERE witness.categoryID = ret.categoryID
    AND witness.weight > ret.weight
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I generally just recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select s.*
from sample_table s
where s.weight = (select max(s2.weight)
                  from sample_table s2
                  where s2.categoryID = s.categoryID
                 );
```

In most databases, this has very good performance and can take advantage of an index on `sample_table(categoryId, weight)`.